# sendBroadcast not working from WorkerThread

Tags: java, android, android-intent, handler

i want to send a Broadcast from a FromTowerThread with the following method:

```
void postToService(final String string){
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable(){
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(string));
             }
        });
    }
```

My context  is 'this' (my service):

```
FromTowerThread ftt = new FromTowerThread(this);
```

(just for completeness my constructor in FromTowerThread):

```
public FromTowerThread(Context context){
      this.context=context;
    }
```

The Error i get is "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()".

I don't know how to fix this error, all threads i found about this topic could not help me to understand this.

Thanks in advance!

Chris

Comment: Try changing the statement  Handler handler = new Handler(); to  Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

Comment: I have added it to the answer, accept it so that it can help others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the statement

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

to

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

Answer (score 0):

> The Error i get is "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()".

If you are extending Thread, try extending [HandlerThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) instead.  A HandlerThread has a Looper already. (Or you can call `Looper.prepare()` and `Looper.loop()` yourself in a regular Thread.)

Otherwise you can do a few things to use the main Thread's Looper.  For instance create the Handler in the main Thread and pass it to your worker Thread or even pass a View from the UI Thread and call `view.post(Runnable)` to execute that Runnable on the UI Thread.

Answer (score 0):

Post can only be done from a Handler in a thread that called Looper.prepare().

I'm assuming here that the thread that calls `void postToService(final String string)` is some type of background thread. Usually the UI thread does call `Looper.prepare()` meaning that you  would have to create the Handler inside the UI thread.

but just as a general suggestion, I'm pretty sure you can just eliminate all of this and just call the broadcast straight away:

```
void postToService(final String string){
      context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(string));
}
```